# How to Load ubuntu with windows 8 boot loader

Tags: grub2, bootloader, windows-8

I have a Toshiba laptop which came with windows 7. I partitioned my hard drive and am now triple booting windows 7,windows 8 consumer preview (installed first),Ubuntu 12.04 (installed second). I would like to be able to use windows 8 boot loader (if possible) to select between the three OS's. currently I start my PC and grub2 loads (I believe this is the name, purple Ubuntu boot loader screen?) where I can choose between Ubuntu or windows 8 loader (not windows 7)if I select windows 8 loader it then starts windows 8 boot loader where I can choose from windows 7 or 8 (not Ubuntu). I need a way to first make windows 8 loader recognize my Ubuntu partition then second, successfully uninstall Grub.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this is a Windows 8 question rather than an Ubuntu question.  I'd have to know how to install and configure Windows 8's bootloader to answer this.  Maybe others can help though.

Comment: @neon_overload I think this is sufficiently about what needs to happen or Ubuntu to boot, that it can be considered on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out !!!

It is straight forward, log into windows 8 and install EasyBCD 2.1.2, after installation run program, select Add New Entry button on the left -> select the Linux/BSD tab -> in the type drop list, select "GRUB (Legacy)" OR "GRUB2" depending on which version you have installed -> Change the Name to whatever you want -> select Add Entry, Next select the BCD Deployment button on the left -> Select Partition 2 or the partition that has the "C:\" drive -> select Write MBR -> Finally reboot computer and your windows 8 boot menu should include your Linux boot information. I am currently running a triple boot with windows 8 release preview, windows 7 ultimate and ubuntu 12.04. and they all boot flawlessly from the windows 8 graphical boot menu.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a live Ubuntu cd/dvd or usb, go to try Ubuntu.
2. Open terminal. Do this commands.

   > sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   >
   > sudo apt-get update
   >
   > sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
   >
   > boot-repair

The Boot Repair window will automatically scan your system after you run the boot-repair command. After it scans your system, click the “Recommended repair” button to repair GRUB2 with a single click.

Reboot. You must be seeing GRUB boot loader with Ubuntu and few option and Windows Boot Loader below those.

Answer (score -2):

I don't remember the name, but I do know there is a bootloader configuration INI in windows (at least in XP). I got that to work with ubuntu.