# How Do I Boot Into Ubuntu Instead Of Windows?

Tags: 12.04, boot

I've just finished install Ubuntu 12.04 onto an additional partition on my single hard-drive.  I'm also running Windows 8.

During the install I created an ext4 partition, a swap partition, and a boot partition as instructed by the Ubuntu installer.  The install completed successfully...but after rebooting it takes me straight into Windows 8.

I tried searching for a similar issue - and found this ([How to Load ubuntu with windows 8 boot loader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132935/how-to-load-ubuntu-with-windows-8-boot-loader)) so I followed those steps, installed EasyBCD 2.2 and tried my best to add Ubuntu.  Now when I boot I get a menu that says 'Ubuntu 1, Ubuntu 2, Ubuntu 3, Windows 8.1' - each added slightly differently - but fail to boot.  Windows 8.1 still works though.

I tried using the boot-repair using instructions found here ([How to install the Boot-Repair tool in an Ubuntu live disc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc)) and I copied/pasted the commands as instructed....but after rebooting I'm taken to the boot menu that appeared after running EasyBCD.

### Can anyone tell me what I can do to boot into Ubuntu without losing my Windows partition?

Here is the output the boot-repair tool has generated:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6815414/

I've tried using the boot-repair too a few times now.  When it begins it says 'EFI detected.  Please check the options'.

The advanced options are:
Main Options
   Reinstall GRUB
   Use the standard EFI file
   Unhide boot menu

GRUB Location
   Os to boot by default sda5
   (checked) Seperate /boot/efi partition sda1

GRUB options
   (checked)SecureBoot

MBR options
   Greyed

Other options
   Repair Windows boot files
   Create BootInfo summary
   Participate to statistics of use
   Check internet connection

When I click apply it says: 'The boot of yoru PC is in Legacy mode.  You may want to retry after changing it to EFI mode.
Do you want to continue?'

No exits.  Yes will bring up the message:  Buggy-kernel detected.  Do you want to activate [Backup and rename Windows EFI files]?  (if any choice fails, please retry with the other).  No matter what response I choose, when I reboot I see the same boot menu from Easy BCD.

Thanks for reading through all this.  I'm really stuck on this one.

Comment: post the pastebin link for your boot-repair log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you have simply used "Recommended repair" in boot-repair then that won't work!

Assuming your laptop has UEFI firmware(If your laptop came with windows 8 preinstalled then it will have UEFI)

Boot from a LIVE CD:

1.Start Boot-Repair, click on "Advanced options", go to the "GRUB location" tab.

2.If you do not see a "Separate /boot/efi partition" line, this means that your PC does not have any EFI partition. In this case, exit Boot-Repair, then create an EFI partition

3.If you see a "Separate /boot/efi partition" line, tick it then click the "Apply" button.(*Even if it is ticked already please tick it again*)

4.Set up your BIOS so that it boots the HDD in EFI mode

For more info have a look at [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks - I'm working through the info in the link - hopefully it'll do the trick.

Comment: You installed Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode. But Windows is in UEFI boot mode. So you do need to boot Boot-Repair in UEFI mode and tick the efi option. It then can uninstall grub-pc(BIOS) and install grub-efi(UEFI).

Comment: What oldfred said is correct..If you follow the link given in answer then you will be able to get GRUB