# How to restore my ubuntu boot loader screen

Tags: bootloader

Today when i was trying to start windows i mistakenly selected system startup and it booted me into the startup screen.
 I press enter and then it booted me into windows and when i restarted it booted staright into windows the Ubuntu booting screen didn't appeared
And now im unable to boot into Ubuntu 
Can anybody tell me how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

You should mention your hardware and software specifications too.

For ubuntu to boot, you need to find key(fn keys) for your hardware(like esc or f10 for hp). Then you simply goes to boot configuration menu and find ubuntu boot loader and put it on top. This way you can boot into Ubuntu. This question would be helpful- [How Do I Boot Into Ubuntu Instead Of Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/410631/how-do-i-boot-into-ubuntu-instead-of-windows)